# What dark matter can AMS currently find (or exclude)?

Tags: particle-physics, astronomy, experimental-physics, dark-matter

The rumor mill is [running again](http://www.space.com/19845-dark-matter-found-nasa-experiment.html), this time it's about the AMS experiment ([Alpha Magnetic Spectrometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer)) that's going to make a major announcement soon.

I suppose they are looking for peaks in gamma and antiproton spectra due to dark matter annihilation. To get a better idea of what kind of results (positive or negative) we can expect, I'm wondering what kind of models they can probe and what their current reach is.

For example, assuming neutralino dark matter, can they strictly exclude $\tilde\chi^0_1$ masses up to $x$ GeV (like LEP)? Or only under such-and-such conditions (e.g. $\tan \beta > \ldots)$? What parameter regions of cMSSM-like SUSY models are within reach, which axion masses, etc.?

Comment: see also http://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/40

Answer (score 5):

The paper containing the first results from AMS can be found [here](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v110/i14/e141102)

As I understand, AMS can make measurements about and above the electroweak symmetry breaking scale ($\mathcal{O}(100\,\text{GeV})$), so it's well placed to make measurements of a number of dark matter candidates.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! It would be kind of you to provide al link, the day it is officially announced.

Comment: @StefanBischof It looks like there is going to be an announcement today by NASA at 1:30 ET. For more information go [here](http://www.nasa.gov/home/hqnews/2013/apr/HQ_M13-054_AMS_Findings_Briefing.html)